# Which order of words is more logical in a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

We are writing an error message for a user and we have two conflicting opinions at the moment. Since we're not native English speakers/writers we may have some issues with punctuation.

Here are the 2 options:

1. "To avoid any further issues program will now close!"
2. "The program will now close to avoid any further issues!"

Which one of those is grammatically correct? If both are correct which is better style?

Comment: Either way works.I would suggest not using bangs.  Oh, and both forms need  "the" before "program".  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62918/why-is-the-exclamation-mark-called-a-bang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1."To avoid any further issues [the] program will now close!"
>
> 2."The program will now close to avoid any further issues!"

There is some subjectivity in this but my immediate instinctive reading without analysing the sentences was:

The first sentence implies

(1) that there is/has been an issue

(2) the user is already aware of that

(3) to avoid things going even more wrong the program is closing

The second sentence says

(1) The program is about to close

(2) The reason for closing is so that the program can spend some time avoiding issues (maybe it has family problems and needs time off work?)

(3) You already knew that the program had issues

In terms of grammar, both sentences are correct. Some people use more punctuation than others. I find your existing punctuation acceptable.

Comment: From this analysis I see that the first sentence would be more suitable in our case.However, is there a better (third) option that would convey the same meaning but also be better in style because the first sentence looks and feels iffy to me.

Comment: Remember that was my subjective impression - others might read it differently. The first question is about 'further'. Does the user know that there is already an issue or is this the first they have heard of it?

Comment: They know there is an issue.

Comment: I would go with sentence 1.  I prefer it with 'the' added.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity's sake, use a comma after *issues* in the first sentence.

To avoid any further issues, the program will now close.